# error performing isolated work whet trying to save Iterable

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, spring-data-jpa

I have the following method:

```
List<BinValue> binValues = Arrays
         .stream(data)
...
         .collect(Collectors.toList());

      binValueRepo.deleteByStatId(databaseGlobals.getMarriedStat().getId());
//      for(BinValue binValue : binValues) {
//         binValueRepo.save(binValue);
//      }
      binValueRepo.save(binValues);
```

First it prepares a list of `BinValue` entities, then tries to save it to repository.

The problem is: if I try to save entire list, the following error occurs:

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: error performing isolated work; SQL [n/a];...

LockAcquisitionException: error performing isolated work

org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
```

if I do this by one, then everything works (but slow).

To fill BinValue I am using the following code:

```
        BinValue ans = new BinValue();
        ans.setBin(bin);
        ans.setRegion(region);
        ...
```

I.e. I am not filling primary key field.

It is defined in the following way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bin_values")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BinValue {

   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   @GeneratedValue(generator="sqlite")
   @TableGenerator(name="sqlite", table="sqlite_sequence",
      pkColumnName="name", valueColumnName="seq",
      pkColumnValue="bin_values")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   private long id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting max connections to 1 solving this problem

```
 @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      BasicDataSource ans = new BasicDataSource();
      ans.setDriverClassName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      ans.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:" + sqliteDatabaseFile().getAbsolutePath());
      ans.setMaxTotal(1);


      return ans;
   }
```